# Catch error from Send-MailMessage cmdlet when called from batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, error-handling

I have a batch file that uses PowerShell's Send-MailMessage cmdlet to send emails out with status updates:

```
powershell -command " & {Send-MailMessage -SMTPServer smtp.somewhere.com -From 'Sender <sender@email.com>' -To 'Recipient <recipient@email.com>' -Subject 'Subject' -Body 'Body' -Attachments 'D:\Logs\Log.log';}"
if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 (
echo ERROR - Something went wrong sending the email
goto Error
)
```

If the Send-MailMessage command fails (e.g. if attachment file not found, or other error), the %ERRORLEVEL% is not raised above 0.

Other answers suggest adding explicit exit codes into a PowerShell script to return a code, but I can't find anything about how to capture an error if using a built in PS cmdlet like Send-MailMessage.  Can it be done, or do I need to wrap Send-MailMessage in another PS script?

Comment: Why do you need the batch script at all? Just run the command from PowerShell (or a PowerShell script).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I just posted a small snippet of the actual batch file which is a bit of a beast.  I could probably spend a few days re-writing the whole thing in PowerShell... but would prefer to keep it in batch if possible

Comment: You can capture the output of other console commands with a `FOR /F` command. So if I am in a batch file and want to subtract from a date I will call out to Powershell and capture the output. `For /F "delims=" %%a In ('PowerShell -Command "&{((Get-Date).AddDays(+1)).ToString('yyyyMMdd')}"') Do Set "d8=%%a"`. You may have to use the `USEBACKQ` option with the `FOR /F` command because you are using single quotes with your powershell code. I think the double quotes are protecting them though.

Comment: @Duodenalsalmons IMO the effort would be well spent - your script will be much easier to read and enhance/fix/extend.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart You are dead right. I'm 2 days into the changeover and it's quite a shift. Thanks for the push.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the whole command in a try catch block and throw an explicit error. This will return a non-zero exit code.

```
powershell -command "Try {Send-MailMessage ... -ErrorAction Stop;} Catch { Exit 1 }"
```

It's a little harder to read in a one line but:

```
powershell -command "Try {Send-MailMessage -SMTPServer smtp.somewhere.com -From 'Sender <sender@email.com>' -To 'Recipient <recipient@email.com>' -Subject 'Subject' -Body 'Body' -Attachments 'D:\Logs\Log.log' -ErrorAction Stop;} Catch { Exit 1 }"
if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 (
echo ERROR - Something went wrong sending the email
goto Error
)
```